# SharePoint hosted app development, Less/Typescript and side-loading

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, debugging

I am doing some technology test for developing SharePoint hosted apps using Visual Studio 2013 in my SharePoint 2013 development environment. 
For that reason, I am trying to see how far I can push the IDE in relation to supporting more recent development technologies like Angularjs, Typescript, Less and such. So far I am favorably impressed - the simple tests I have done have worked as expected, and I am able to use Less and Typescript in my solution.

Just one thing is bugging me of: as I quickly noticed, using a developer-site enables me to side-load the application and be able to perform quick changes to the code from VS and having them reflected in the browser after I refresh the page.

Sadly, this don't work for the .less and .ts files, as VS seem to not mark the associated .css and .js dirty when the parent files are updated (yes, I have "compile on save" activated, so the files **are** updated "realtime"). This cause side-load to fail. To have it work, it is enough to add a space to the real .css and .js files and save them.

Anyone knows of a way/extension that would allow me to have the file "side-loaded" without taking this additional step?